# call DateTimePicker in wordpress Gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

This should be relatively easy I imagine, however I cannot figure it out.

I am creating a custom Gutenberg block in JSX with React components which has an attribute I call `datetime`. Using the block you can choose a date and time that will be saved to the database and rendered on the front-end.

Using the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/date-time/) I import all dependencies and created a `const` like this:

```
const MyDateTimePicker = withState( {
    date: new Date(),
} )( ( { date, setState } ) => {
    const settings = __experimentalGetSettings();

    // To know if the current timezone is a 12 hour time with look for an "a" in the time format.
    // We also make sure this a is not escaped by a "/".
    const is12HourTime = /a(?!\\)/i.test(
        settings.formats.time
            .toLowerCase() // Test only the lower case a
            .replace( /\\\\/g, '' ) // Replace "//" with empty strings
            .split( '' ).reverse().join( '' ) // Reverse the string and test for "a" not followed by a slash
    );

    return (
        <DateTimePicker
            currentDate={ date }
            onChange={ ( date ) => setState( { date } ) }
            is12Hour={ is12HourTime }
        />
    );
} );
```

My question is: **how do I call this?**

I tried `{ MyDateTimePicker }`, `{ MyDateTimePicker() }` and `<button onClick={ MyDateTimePicker }>test</button>`. None of this seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about [Edit and Save functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/)

On edit you'd use it somehow like this assuming you already defined the attribute datetime as needed:

```
const { Fragment, createElement } = window.wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = window.wp.editor;
const { Panel, PanelBody, PanelRow, DateTimePicker } = window.wp.components;

export default function edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {

  const { datetime } = attributes;

  const onUpdateDate = ( dateTime ) => {
    var newDateTime = moment(dateTime).format( 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm' );
    setAttributes( { datetime: newDateTime } );
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody
            title="Some title for the date-tile panel"
            icon=""
            initialOpen={ false }
        >
          <PanelRow>
            <DateTimePicker
                currentDate={ datetime }
                onChange={ ( val ) => onUpdateDate( val ) }
                is12Hour={ true }
            />
          </PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

On the save function, you could display the output easily like this:

```
const { createElement, Fragment } = window.wp.element;
export default function save( { attributes } ) {

    const { datetime } = attributes;

    return (
        <Fragment>
        { datetime ?
      <div>
        <p>The Date-Time: <span>{datetime}</span></p>
      </div> :
        <p>No date defined</p>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

**Note:** the example above will display the date-time picker in the block editor right panel on its own panel row, if you want it displayed differently or as a part of some action you'd need to get a little creative and create you own React components.

Comment: helpful example. The only problem I have is that `datetime` is stored as a string and not an integer. I tried to change the attribute type in my JS, but that did not work, it is still stored as a string. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with an integer assuming this is saved for front-end view. Could you explain the purpose?